# python generator for..in vs next()

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, iterator, generator

I'm a bit confused by python's generators, and using a `for` loop vs using `next()` on them.

I need to parse a text file that contains information about i.e. cars on each line, each car having multiple non-mandatory lines after the mandatory line with the model name that starts with an `a.`. So I want to iterate over the cars in a pythonic fashion.

I have the following bit of code:

```
lines = """a. car1 model
b. car1 price
c. car1 details
a. car2 model
b. car2 price
a. car3 model
b. car3 price
c. car3 details
d. car3 comments
"""

def iter_cars(lineit):
   res = []
   for line in lineit:
       if line.startswith('a') and res:
           yield res
           res = []

       res.append(line)
   yield res

# print the cars with next..., 
lineit = iter(lines.split('\n'))
print(next(iter_cars(lineit)))
print(next(iter_cars(lineit)))
print(next(iter_cars(lineit)))

# reset the iterator and print the cars with for
lineit = iter(lines.split('\n'))
for car in iter_cars(lineit):
    print(car)
```

and the output is:

```
# using next()
a. car1 model
b. car1 price
c. car1 details

b. car2 price

b. car3 price
c. car3 details
d. car3 comments


# using for..in
a. car1 model
b. car1 price
c. car1 details

a. car2 model
b. car2 price

a. car3 model
b. car3 price
c. car3 details
d. car3 comments
```

Why are the two outputs different? Why is `next()` skipping the `a.` line of each car after the first? How can I rewrite the iterator so that using `next()` yields (chuckles) the same result as using `for..in`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are instantiating the generator each time. Try this

```
gen = iter_cars(lineit)
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

Comment: That was it! I feel so dumb. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, have a beautiful day!

Comment: Thanks, you too! :)